Layer disappeared or not properly show in print layout QGIS
When I make just a standard print layout it looks ok, all layers show properly.

But when I tried to make this one with the circle to have a nice-looking polar-style map, one of the most critical elements (glaciated areas layer), ironically was missed or only partially displayed.

I used QGIS 3.28.11, a dataset from Naturearthdata, and EPSG 3995 projection.

Can you provide example data and a copy of your layout?

I don't know how to do it properly... it's data from Naturearthdata, the name of the layer -   ne_10m_glaciated_areas
